# Calling a php include from content stored in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am building a website with content retrieved from a MySQL database. The urls are re-written to a single file simplified as so:

```
<html>
 <head>...</head>
 <body>
   <div id="header"></div>

   <?php $content = (html content retrieved from db for the current page); ?>

       <div id="content">
        <?php echo "$content"; ?>
       </div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
 </body>
```

Almost all of the pages are a simple h1 tag and a few p tags, and this works fine for simple text pages:

```
$content = '<h1>Title</h1>
<p>First paragraph of text</p>
<p>Second paragraph of text</p>';
```

however I need some pages to include PHP files within the content. for example:

```
$content = '
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>First paragraph of text</p>
include(imageSlideshow.php)
<p>Second paragraph of text</p>';
```

The same content in the PHP include files will be displayed in several pages and sometimes multiple includes will need to be on the same page so I don't want to store the code in the include files within the database content. Is it possible to retrieve the content from the db but somehow reference a PHP include from within that content?

The only ways I can think of to achieve this are either 1:

have a unique sting within the content stored in the database like so

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>First paragraph of text</p>
*KJNJNILKN*imageSlideshow*KJNJNILKN*
<p>Second paragraph of text</p>
```

then use PHP to seek out any such references to *KJNJNILKN* then parse the content within as an include file before displaying the content on the page or, 2:

I have one table storing the pages and another storing the content, with each page having multiple content rows if necessary like so:

```
content table:
id   pageId   contentPosition   contentType   content
1      1             1          html          <h1>Title</h1><p>First para</p>
2      1             2          include       imageSlideshow
3      1             3          html          <p>Second para</p>
```

I can then handle the 'content' data accordingly.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could use the eval() function to process the string. Make sure that the string is valid PHP code:

```
$content = '
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>First paragraph of text</p>
include(imageSlideshow.php)
<p>Second paragraph of text</p>';

eval($content);
```